# Difference between Expo vs Exp on command line

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, exp

I've been using expo/exp for a while to build React Native applications and can't seem to find clear documentation on what the diffeence between `exp` and `expo` is on the command line.

Could someone please elaborate?

[image]

Comment: For the new/confused, `expo` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs of [expo-cli](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/expo-cli) and [exp-cli](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/workflow/exp-cli), expo-cli includes not only cli but also XDE, and exp-cli only includes cli which is useful when you don't need a full-fledged development environment such as in CI.

Answer (score 2):

"exp" is our original command-line interface. "expo_cli" is our new dev tools that we see as the best path moving forward as it combines the best of both worlds from the exp CLI and our XDE gui. You can read more about it here: https://blog.expo.io/announcing-expo-dev-tools-beta-c252cbeccb36

The latest [docs](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/) recommend using expo-cli, and not exp.

So, start with **`$ expo init`** instead of `$ exp init`.

Comment: You guys really need to do a better job of documenting changes like this. Tweeting and blog posts is not enough. When new users come to expo they encounter the old references and don't likely read your whole blog!